# File of custom type are not searchable in Alfresco using Advance search

Tags: search

I am seeing below behavior in Alfresco and read lots of relates doumentaion of alfresco but not found any clear answer.

Below are things I have done to search a file.
1. Uploaded a file named "Test.txt" in a folder having only one rule to have custom type on the uploaded docs.
2. And when I select content in "look for" option in advance search then my test file comes in result of search.
as shown below.

3. Then I have searched it using advance search using name property and selecting my custom type in the "look for" option in advance search then it result 0 files.
4. But when I set any property of test.txt file it becomes searchable using custom type in Advance search.

My question is If I just upload a file. How can it become searchable using custom type in Advance search.?
When is the indexing generated of files uploaded of custom type.

I am using Alfresco 4.1 and Solr as search engine.

Thanks,
Fouad

Answer (score 0):

SOLR indexes Alfresco every 15 seconds by default, so there's no reason why your uploaded file wouldn't be indexed right away.

Are you sure your rule actually works?
I'd suggest taking the file's nodeRef, and using Node Browser to look at it's type, aspects and properties right after it enters the folder (and triggers the rule), and after you change something by hand. That might clear something up, as in why it works/does not work.

Additionally, you could search for unindexed nodes and see if your file is there:
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/solr-index-fix.html

Comment: I have checked document after upload in node browser it is uploaded as my custom type. But it is searchable by selecting content in the advance search means it is indexed right?

Comment: Yes I again verified as you said after just upload the document becomes of my custom type as expected, But only few properties are showing on the node browser from all the properties defined in the content model.  But when i update any properties of the document all the properties defined on that type shows up in node browser.